# Create a python venv that works on systems with no python installed

Tags: python, python-import, python-venv, python-packaging

How do I setup a virtual environment in such a way that is can be used to call a python script, but doesn't need a system wide python.

My goal is it to have one folder with the python script in it and python itself in that folder as well with all the libs I need for that python script.

I've tried using pycharm to manage my venv, but the venv py charm creates needs a system wide python for the venv python to work. (I'm quite sure this is because of the pyvenv.cfg file which needs reference to a system wide python).

At the end of the day I don't care if I create the venv with pycharm or some other tool, I just want this to work. Any suggestions?

What I don't want, is  to compile it to an executable.

Comment: Maybe you could try a [*zipapp*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html)-based solution such as [*pex*](https://pypi.org/project/pex/) or [*shiv*](https://pypi.org/project/shiv/). Unless you really need to have a folder (assuming maybe you want to make changes in the code or something like that). -- What should we understand "*but doesn't need a system wide python"*? -- For info: virtual environments are not relocatable, they can not be renamed or moved to another place on disk on the same machine or on another machine, so that probably would not have worked anyway.

Comment: That's not a virtual environment; that's just a regular Python environment in a non-standard location.

Comment: Why can virtual environments not be moved, the venv has everything it needs to function (a full python and all libs)?

Comment: Because the configuration of virtual environments contain absolute paths. And, no, virtual environments do not contain a full Python and all its libraries. The original Python interpreter (and its standard library) used to create the virtual environment are necessary to use the virtual environment after its creation.

Comment: Then how do change that, giving python all it needs as well as relative paths. I want to be able to run python scripts on systems with no python, and also want that anyone can directly be able to look at the script to see what it does. I don't understand why I'm the only one who wants this, I've searched far and wide and not found a single person talking about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simply, virtual environments are the wrong thing for this situation. Portable/ embedded Python is the correct thing. A video to that here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8kgu74jERM

Answer (score 1):

The way to go is NOT through a virtual environment in this case.
I had to do it in the company I work - because some computers don't have internet.

0. create in you internet-connected computer a directory,
   into which you will install all the packages.
   Let's call it `env`.
   `$ mkdir -p /path/to/env`
1. When installing the required packages, add to `pip install` simply:
   `-t /path/to/env` (`t` for target directory)
   so:
   `pip install -t /path/to/env packagename`
2. Transfer your `env` folder to your offline computer (via usb or whatever)
3. add `/path/to/env` to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable
   In Linux or mac add to `~/.bashrc` into its content:
   `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/env:$PYTHONPATH`
   In Windows, add to your: `$profile.CurrentUserAllHosts`:
   `$env:PYTHONPATH=C:/path/to/env;${$env:PYTHONPATH}` (use `;` as delimiter!)
   `PYTHONPATH` determines where your Python looks for packages.
   The order matters - from left to right it is searched through.
4. `source ~/.bashrc` in Linux
   `. $profile.CurrentUserAllHosts` in Windows
   to make the entered changes be executed, thus valid.

Voila, now your Python will be able to find the packages in your folder!

systemwide or non-systemwide python

I don't know - I didn't tried myself.

You can start a local python by just giving the
absolute path to the python.exe (windows) or python binary (linux/mac=unix-derived).

In unix-derived systems, you can do:

```
env PYTHONPATH=/path/to/env /path/to/python /path/to/script.py
```

to make the PYTHONPATH only valid for this call.

In windows, you could do it using a function e.g. in PowerShell

```
myscript () {
  local PATH=/path/to/python;$env:PYTHON
  local PYTHONPATH=/path/to/env
  python /path/to/script.py
}

myscript
```

Then, outside the function, the variable stays unchanged.

Comment: This doesn't work. I install Python and use it to create a venv. Then execute the activate in my cmd and call a python script "py ..\..\testScript\helloWorld.py" for example. This works fine. When I however delete my system python and try this again, then I get the error that the system python was not found. Why can't this venv be used to call python script it has everything python needs to run, it's ridiculous that python needs to be installed on the system.

Comment: Even when doing this I get the error that the python used to create the venv is missing:

"env PYTHONPATH=/path/to/env /path/to/python /path/to/script.py". It's all because of the stupid pyvenv.cfg file

Comment: are you using linux or windows?

Comment: in this you don't use any venv - you just use your normal python and pip

Comment: usually, python looks first in the folder where it is - so actually if you put your package sinto the same folder like the binary of python which you use, it should find then the packages even wtihout PYTHONPATH

Comment: but for that your python binary should be inside the env folder and you shoul best open terminal within the env folder and run `python script.py` - everything should be then in this folder.

Comment: in this way you would need only `pip install -t /path/to/env packagename` as your trick

Comment: This is on an up to date windows 10 system

Comment: try then the corrected myscript function in my answer

Comment: `myscript () {
  local PATH=C:\Users\sidney\Desktop\project\venv\Scripts;$env:PYTHON
  local PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\sidney\Desktop\project\venv
  python C:\Users\sidney\Desktop\project\testScript\helloWorld.py
}

myscript`
`

So this is what it would look like for me? And what would I do now (I put it in a .ps1 file and executed it in a powershell window)

Comment: you execute that .ps1 file using dot operator in powershell `. /path/to/your.ps1` and then can call `myscript` in powershell